# Is any way to get llvm deference pointer value's raw type(i.e. pointer type)

Tags: c++, c, llvm, clang++, llvm-clang

Maybe the title is somehow confused. but let me show you a example.

```
void foo(int val)
{
    // do something
}

int i = 27;
int* pi = &i;

foo(*pi);
```

Here, if we compile it using clang, the type of *pi will be i32, but we know pi is pointer type.

my question is we use Function::getgetFunctionParamType method, the result will be i32. but how do I use some wayst to get ' pi ' type, not ' *pi ' type?  This problem has confused me some days.

Update:

I see some people confused this question. Alright, I have compiled this source code to the LLVM intermediate format flie(i.e. .ll file), so I have reached the step that intermediate code generation, what I can handle is LLVM IR related and I can only see i32, i32* and so on(there is no int, int* now). And I do not want to construct one pointer type, I just somehow want to 'reverse' *pi to pi so that I can check 'pi' is pointer type. The situation is like this: I have *pi, in the .ll file, maybe pi is

```
%pi = alloca i32*, align 32 
%1 = load i32** %pi, align 32  
%2 = load volatile i32* %1, align 1
%3 = call foo(i32 %2)
```

so if I check the argument type of function, I can only get i32, because it is *pi now. But if I can get pi, i.e. %pi = alloca i32* align 32, I can know pi is pointer type.

Comment: Not clear what is your question

Comment: [Just add an asterisk so it's `i32*`](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#pointer-type)?

Comment: *"type of *pi will be i32*" No, the resulting type of `*pi` will be `int`, as `pi` is defined `int *`..

Comment: @alk: he's talking about LLVM IR, which doesn't have `int`.

Comment: @Cornstalks: So can't the OP then use `i32` but `int`?

Comment: @alk: not really. He's got the original C/C++ code, as shown (so he can't use `i32` there). It gets compiled by LLVM to its IR (now it's `i32`, and `int` no longer exists). Now he's working with the IR, and wants "reverse" some of the IR to match closer to the C/C++ code (which means making a pointer, like the original code did). At least that's how I understand this question.

Comment: There's no way to statically determine how a function was called, since a program could call it in many ways (`foo(*pi)`, `foo(i)`, `foo(42)`, etc.); all you can tell by looking at the function is that the the argument had a type convertible to the parameter type `int`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: True, but that is not the question. I could imagine that a tool which generates code would need to determine `T*` so it can declare `T* pt`, when the generated code intends to call `foo(*pt)`.

Comment: @MSalters: OK, I guess I misinterpreted the question. It reads to me like it's asking how to deduce the pointer type from the parameter type, but maybe it's just too early on a Monday for my reading comprehension skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly what you need are the Operands of the `CallInst` calling the function, not the function declaration.

Assuming you have your `Function* F` pointing to `foo(i32)`:

(I write from mind so sorry if it won't compile)

```
for(auto U : F->users())
{
    if (CallInst* CI = dyn_cast<CallInst>(U))
    {
        Value* O0 = CI->getOperand(0) // we simply know foo needs one operand
        if (Constant* C = dyn_cast<Constant>(O0))
        {
            // parameter is a constant you can get the type as usual from every value
        }
        else if (LoadInst* LI = dyn_cast<LoadInst>(O0))
        {
            // since the argument is not a constant it must be a value loaded by
            // a LoadInst and LoadInst has the function getPointerOperand()
            Value* PO = LI->getPointerOperand();
            // since we know it's a pointer Operand we can cast safely here
            PointerType* PT = cast<PointerType>(PO->getType());
            PT->dump(); // will print i32* 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [`PointerType* PointerType::get(Type*)`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1PointerType.html#a050a395d1656e546679d8b144d951bb2)

Comment: Thanks, but in fact I do not want to construct one pointer type from one element. The situation is like this: I have *pi, in the .ll file, maybe pi is   %pi = alloca i32*, align 32 %1 = load i32** %pi, align 32  %2 = load volatile i32* %1, align 1
%3 = call foo(i32 %2),  so if I check the argument type of function, I can only get i32, because it is *pi now. But if I can get pi, i.e. %pi = alloca i32* align 32, I can know pi is pointer type.